# rails cutting string when passing arabic word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
here is my controller class

  def create
   @test_topic = TestTopic.new(test_topic_params)
    if @test_topic.save
     redirect_to testing_index_path
    else
     render 'new'
  end
end
```

i have a controller class which creates topics with title , hashtags and keywords. when i pass arabic word in any of these parameters it 
    cuts some part of the word from start, like if i pass 
    `'باحثون_عن_عمل_يستغيثون'` it saves only `'ن_عن_عمل_يستغيثون'`.
it displays full word in web view but when i check in db and console it dosen't shows the full word.

Comment: Can you please specify the encoding type you are using?
It can be seen in database.yml

Comment: there is no encoding type specified in database.yml

Comment: Can you please check which encoding type suits best for Arabic, I guess it's utf-8.

Comment: i tried both utf-8 and unicode but nothing works